# Can't get the error to hit a catch block while running query on datastore

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore, es6-promise

I'm passing an undefined parameter to the below method causing datastore client to:

*throw new Error('Unsupported field value, ' + value + ', was provided.');
Error: Unsupported field value, undefined, was provided.*

I'm expecting the inner catch statement to be hit with the error but neither that one nor the outer try catch is getting hit. The error handling middle isn't catching this error either and it's crashing my expressjs app.

```
getUserByEmail(email) {
    try {
        return datastore
            .createQuery("user")
            .filter("email", "=", email)
            .limit(1)
            .run()
            .then(results => {
                var entities = results[0][0];
                return entities;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
                return null;
            });
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return null;
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you sure to be passing `undefined` to the method? From the codebase, it looks like you should be getting the error mentioned in the question.

Comment: Yes, I should be getting the error. I'm trying to make sure I can catch the error properly. I'm passing an undefined variable to this method to test.

Answer (score 0):

[`Promise.prototype.catch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) will handle the errors thrown by the asynchronous flow execution of the Promise.

Where as in your code, the error is being trigged by the synchronous flow. That's the reason the outer catch gets executed.

**update**

You've caught `error` but logging `err`. Correcting this, should work

```
function getUserByEmail(email) {
  try {
    throw new Error('Unsupported field value');
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.error(error); // please use `error` instead of `err`
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Right. In that case, should the outer catch statement not be hit? In my case the error is crashing the app. It's not getting caught by express error handling middleware either. I'm editing the question with these

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually, the app isn't even hitting the breakpoints. Just tried it anyway. The same thing. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

You are catching `error` and printing `err`. I think that's the reason app is crashing.

```
catch (error) {
        console.error(err);
        return null;
    }
```

@Sridhar is right about the synchronous execution. I think that is what you intend to know from this question.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is not the issue, unfortunately. Look at the comment I posted